# Is there a more efficient way of controlling css elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I already solved it, but I was just wondering if there was a more efficient way of writing the code

```
function p(){
    document.getElementById("boom").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("boom1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("boom2").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("boom3").style.display = "block";
}
p();
```

The result is what I expected but I was just wondering if there is an easier way to write it

Comment: use a common class, get all elements and iterate to apply style

Answer (score 1):

You can use a common class for all elements to group them(or use combined selector), then get all elements using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)(or [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) if using common class) method  and for iterating over the returned [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) collection use [`NodeList#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) method([polyfill for older browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Polyfill)).

```
function p(){
    document.querySelectorAll(".common-class").forEach(ele => ele.style.display = "block");
    // or .forEach(({style}) => style.display = "block");
}

p();
```

```js
function p() {
  var all = document.querySelectorAll(".common-class");
  all.forEach(({ style }) => style.display = "block");
}
p();
```

```css
div {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div id="boom" class="common-class">boom</div>
<div id="boom1" class="common-class">boom1</div>
<div id="boom2" class="common-class">boom2</div>
<div id="boom3" class="common-class">boom3</div>
```